# WKInterfaceTable detect which row selected

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I just need to check which row was selected to pass data between `WKInterfaceController`. Here is my code, but NSLog doesn't show anything:

```
- (void)loadTableData {

     NSArray* items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cell 1 ",@"cell2 ", @"cell 3",@"cell4",nil];

    // Configure the table object (self.todoItems) and get the row controllers.
    [self.myTable setNumberOfRows:items.count withRowType:@"DinoNameRow"];
    NSInteger rowCount = self.myTable.numberOfRows;

    // Iterate over the rows and set the label for each one.
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        // Get the to-do item data.
        NSString* itemText = items[i];

        // Assign the text to the row's label.
        DinoNameRow* row = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:i];
        [row.dinoName setText:itemText];
    }
}
- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {

    switch (rowIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"ROW 1");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your table connected via IBOutlet to your table element in storyboard?

Comment: Did you set the rowType in Storyboard to "DinoNameRow"? Also, did you set the class of your name controller in Storyboard to "DinoNameRow"?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you breakpoint and type po rowIndex in the console? Are you able to breakpoint at all here?

Comment: @hgwhittle Yes everything is checked and is right , I can display my

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that...

1. Your `WKInterfaceTable` is connected via IBOutlet to your Storyboard element.
2. Your rowType identifier for the row controller is set in Storyboard:[image]
3. Your Class identifier for the row controller is set in Storyboard:
   [image]
4. You have overridden the correct `WKInterfaceController` method:

   ```
   override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {

   }
   ```

Comment: In the step 3 , the Modulation is blank for me ! how should I fill it ? even my main IntefaceContoller is blank ! ! ! other parts are all OK !

Comment: Those should be set with the Watch Extension's module name. In your file navigator pane on the left, you're looking for the folder that contains all your Watch classes. Should be something like `<YourAppName>Watch Extension`. Set that in the module field with underscores for spaces.

Comment: AHA !!! I found the solution that's because of I add `PUSH SEGUE to `another view Controller ! that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

The code as below that I use in my project works well.

```
  override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
        let string = data[rowIndex]
        self.delegate?.didSeletStyle(style, string: string, index: rowIndex)
        popController()
    }

  private func reloadTable() {
        for i in 0 ..< table.numberOfRows {
            let row = table.rowControllerAtIndex(i) as! tableRow
            row.label.setText(data[i])
        }
    }

private func getData(style: Style) {
    if style == .Friend {
        data = ["a","b","c","d"]
    }

    table.setNumberOfRows(data.count, withRowType: "tableRow")
    reloadTable()
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I am trying to convert it to Obj c and then see what happens